# what is GAE webapp2 POST data max limit?

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, http, http-post

Is there a maximum limit for webapp2 POST size? I have an android app that connects to a test development server using python webapp2 on my local machine, and when I do a HTTP POST to the dev server, i get a java Exception on my android when the POST is over 1108 KB in size.

If it helps, im using HttpConnection in the android code.

exact error message from Java: "Content-Length exceeds limit 1108 kB"

Comment: I am pretty sure I have posted more than that - dont have an answer for you but maybe you could show your android code snippet?

Comment: suggest you try deploying it and seeing if the behaviour is the same. The dev server has some shortcomings.

Comment: The hard limit is actually [32MB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Requests), so the issue should be somewhere else. (Devserver shouldn't have this limit, so the issue is definitely somewhere in your code)